# Solving detergent powder in a solution

Tags: bond, aqueous-solution, electrostatic-energy

I used a detergent powder mixed with water to clean my espresso machine. Some micro particles of powder are stuck into machine's inner tank. So when I pull the hot water out of the machine's nozzle, it contains micro powders and it tastes powdery.
What solution can I use instead of water to wash out all those sticky powders?
A harmless solution to break bond between powders and solve the powder into itself.

Comment: Water until everything is gone. Everything means both dust and soapy taste.

Comment: Some coffee pot makers recommend using white vinegar; boil it thru the system, then boil some water thru the system to "rinse" it. Perhaps some coffee oils are holding some non-soluble material from the detergent powder.

Answer (score -1):

I think using acetone will be helpful. Acetone will evaporate fastly and it is polar and can form hydrogen bonds to the detergent powder like water. Though you need to use much acetone to wash all detergent powders and after that, wait for some minutes for acetone to vaporize from your machine.

Comment: Acetone may be a disaster, if there is any plastic.